# Using more than one peer in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have recently deployed and started a business-network with Hyperledger Composer, I have only one peer (?) in which I have created the network and now I am using the rest-server for adding participant and doing transaction from an Android app to my personal blockchain and everything goes well.

So...Need I to configure one or more peers on my network? What's the utility of doing that?

I know that other blockchains needs a lot of peers for co-validating transactions and for maintaining a big scalability / distributed data; doesn't Hyperledger do it for me without adding more peers in my network?

Answer (score 0):

If you have started with Hyperledger Composer you are probably using the 'standard' development Fabric with a Single Peer.  This is a 'minimal' Fabric provided to get developers a fast start without the need to configure and deploy a Fabric.  But you are correct Hyperleder Fabric can be configured for Multi Peer Multi Organisation distributed ledgers.

There are [tutorials](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials.html) in the Fabric documentation for setting up a Fabric from scratch, and also [this document](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-add-an-organization-to-your-hyperledger-fabric-blockchain/index.html) covers a tool for extending the Fabric.

Comment: With my Single Peer in my "standard" development Fabric how can I do the "consensus"? Is it done by the only one peer created by me?